# sendEmail -- unknown key [message-content-type]

Tags: linux, bash

While trying to send HTML content as email using command sendEmail

```
sendEmail -f "from@example.com" -t "to@example.com" -u "Subject" -o message-content-type=html -o message-file=/tmp/file.html -s mailserver:25
```

getting error

```
sendEmail[16719]: WARNING => Name/Value pair [message-content-type=html] will be ignored: unknown key [message-content-type]
```

Comment: Maybe `-o content-type=html`?

Comment: No, same error 
`Name/Value pair [content-type=html] will be ignored: unknown key [content-type]`